# Select * from (every table in an subselect)

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-11g

I was trying to get an select * from (for column table result) every table_name with the result bellow, how can i achieve this?

```
(SELECT a.table_name
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND c_pk.table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME')
```

like:

suppose that the result above was:

- **TABLE_NAME**
- TABLE_LOG_NOD
- TABLE_LOG_CASH
- TABLE_LOG_PLUG

i want to return an select * from (only one row of that table)every one of those tables listed.
Beware i cannot use variable, or any other thing related to PL/SQL, so only SQL.

Sorry for my bad english.
I hope it was clear.
Thank you anyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without using PL/SQL or a loop to generate the SQL in the program you're using to execute the SQL.